# std::enable_if_t typedef substitutions aren't equivalent

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, sfinae, enable-if

I often make a `this_type` typedef for classes to shorten member function signatures.
However, I ran across this oddity when using `std::enable_if_t`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>    

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct foo;

template <class T>
struct foo <T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>
{
    T data {};
    //typedef foo<T, void> this_type; // <-- can't do this
    //typedef foo<T, std::enable_if_t<true>> this_type; // <- can't do this either

    typedef foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>> this_type; // have to do this
    foo () = default;
    explicit foo(T i): data(i) {}
    foo (this_type const &) = default;
    static constexpr auto isame = std::is_same_v<this_type, foo<T, void>>;
};
```

You can't use completely equivalent types in the definition of `this_type` -- the error is, of course, that `foo (this_type const &)` can't be defaulted because `this_type` doesn't match the actual class.

And yet they are all the same type:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::boolalpha(std::cout);
    std::cout << "enable_if_t: " << typeid(std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<int>>).name() << '\n';
    foo<int> myfoo{1};
    std::cout << "Same: " << std::is_same_v<decltype(myfoo), foo<int, void>> << '\n';
    std::cout << "ISame: " << decltype(myfoo)::isame << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(myfoo)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo<int, void>).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(foo<int>::this_type).name() << '\n';

    foo<int> myfoo2(myfoo);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC output:

```
enable_if_t: v
Same: true
ISame: true
3fooIivE
3fooIivE
3fooIivE
```

And the compiler should know this as soon as the specialization succeeds: The result of `std::enable_if_t` is immediately replaced by the type, in this case `void`. And the sample output bears it out.

I thought this might be related to problems created by an old C++ standard between typedefs of the same type at namespace scope, but this is is not the cause, because otherwise `typedef foo<T, std::enable_if_t<true>> this_type` would have worked.

What is preventing the shorter type aliases from being recognized?

---

It's been pointed out in a comment that the shorter aliases work in clang.  However, MSVC's behavior is the same as gcc.

Comment: It looks you can just define it as `typedef foo this_type;`

Comment: this is why specializations are hard to work with.  `struct foo <T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>` doesn't actually exists.  Your main type is `foo<T, __unnamed>`.  It's only when you pass something to `__unnamed` that satisfies `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>` that you get the specialization

Comment: It seems [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sDfvSK7fAL4yOlfP) works fine.

Comment: @songyuanyao  Yes, it does! But MSVC has the same behavior as gcc.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Yet the compiler has all of that information when building the full specialization of `foo<int, void>`.  Is it necessary for the `default` to be processed (and rejected) earlier?

Comment: @Spencer Your specialization is not `foo<int, void>`, it is `struct foo <T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>>`

Comment: @NathanOliver  I just got an answer that says the opposite of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compiler bug in GCC (and MSVC).

The compiler is not permitted to preemptively reject your template declaration just because it cannot figure out whether the member declaration `foo (this_type const &) = default;` is always going to be legal for each instantiation. If there is a possibility of an ill-formed instantiation, it must  reject the program if such an ill-formed instantiation actually occurs (*i.e.* one for which `this_type` is not the same type as the enclosing class type, making this signature not eligible for defaulting). The compiler can also reject the program if it can tell that *all* instantiations would be ill-formed, but that isn't the case for your code. See [[temp.res.general]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6).

The determination of whether a constructor of a class template is a copy constructor is not made until the class template is actually instantiated. At that point, the answer is always known because under [[class.copy.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1), only a **non-template** constructor can be a copy constructor (though template constructors can still be selected by overload resolution to perform copies). So, when you define a class template `foo`, and that class template contains a non-template constructor `C`, the compiler cannot always immediately know whether `C` will be a copy constructor, since the signature of `C` might contain a dependent type. However, when the compiler instantiates some `foo<T>`, then the concrete type of the member `C` of `foo<T>` will be known (since `T` has been supplied) which means, at that point, the compiler can tell whether or not `C` is a copy constructor. Again, this is made possible by the fact that the copy constructor cannot have any of *its own* template parameters and still be considered a copy constructor; so its signature is known as soon as the enclosing concrete class type is known.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply define it as

```cpp
typedef foo this_type;
// or
using this_type = foo;
```

`foo` in this context is an [injected-class-name](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.pre#def:injected-class-name), which refers to the current specialization of `foo`.
There is no need to provide template arguments explicitly.

The reason why `foo<T, void>` doesn't refer to `foo` is that [type equivalence for templates](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#1) needs [expression equivalence](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#def:equivalent,expressions) of template arguments.

`foo<int, void>` and `foo<int>` are the same type, but that's because none of the template arguments are dependent.
This is similar to how `A<42>` and `A<40+2>` are considered equivalent in [[temp.over.link] note 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#note-3).

Comment: Then the `isame` member I just added should have returned `false`.

Comment: That citation from the Standard is a real haystack; you're going to have to pick out the needles.

Comment: @Spencer `std::is_same` still works because it simply gets instantiated and then the compiler checks the `::value` member in the trait. It's not the same for the copy constructor though because the compiler must know that `foo(this_type const&) = default;` is defaulting the copy constructor without instantiating this member. Class template members in are only instantiated when they are used.

Comment: So, the full answer depends on when the `= default` is processed.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the standard covers this issue one way or the other, and I don't think the citations I've given obviously prove it one way or the other. I suspect that it's IFNDR and it works for MSVC and Clang due to memoization.

Comment: Just for clang, not MSVC.

Comment: Notice that @BrianBi disagrees with you.